# Python 2.7: import performance

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

currently, I am importing bunch of .py files scattered across the file system via:

```
def do_import(name):
    import imp

    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(name)
    with fp:
        return imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, description)

known_py_files = ['workingDir/import_one.py', 'anotherDir/import_two.py'] # and so forth
for py_file in known_py_files:
    do_import(py_file)
```

when I've timed the .py files as such below, they are in the magnitude of e-5 and e-6.

import_one.py

```
import time

import_stime = time.time()
import_dur = time.time() - import_stime
print import_dur
```

However, the call to do_import() is in the magnitude of e-3. I am guessing because of the overhead of importing it.

This is a problematic for me because im importing lots of files serially and the time to import adds up.

Is there a faster way to import than the approach mentioned above?

Comment: why not just create a package instead of scattering your files all over the harddrive?

Comment: @MSeifert by creating a package you mean putting __init__.py files?

Answer (score 1):

If all of the files are under one directory, you can create an `__init__.py` empty file in each level of the nested directory, and import the name of the root directory, like `import root` in the following example:

```
/ root
    - __init__.py
    / workingDir
        - __init__.py
        - import_one.py
    / anotherDir
        - __init__.py
        - import_two.py
```

That structure is called "package".

Comment: then importing "root" automatically imports all of the *.py files?

Comment: yes, but you need to remember putting `__init__.py` in every directory with the wanted modules

Comment: just want to be clear. when I call do_import() it acutally executes the code i.e. print out how much it took to import. importing "root" alone will execute all of the .py files right?  is there anything that needs to be written in __init__.py files?

Comment: hmm i wrote a simple test but importing "root" doesnt  look like it actually executes the import_one.py nor import_two.py file

Comment: i would actually have to "import root.workingDir.import_one" and vice versa for the rest

Comment: is there a call which would import the whole package?

Comment: you can add imports to all of the same level modules in every `__init__.py` and then `from root import *` would import all

Comment: "from root import *" all didnt execute import_one.py nor import_two.py